# pthread_mutex_t in multiple processes...who destroys it?

Tags: linux, pthreads

I'm using a pthread_mutex_t to synchronize access to a resource between multiple processes which are on the same level (i.e. there isn't a parent/child relationship).

How can I determine when it's safe to call pthread_mutex_destroy? The only way I can think of to determine if the mutex is in use by another process without introducing a race condition is to introduce another mutex.

Comment: "I'm using a pthread_mutex_t ... between multiple processes". I find this unlikely, as a PThreads mutexes are local to individual processes. Perhaps you're thinking of SYSV mutexes or a different implementation?

Comment: You create them in shared memory and call pthread_mutexattr_setpshared with PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED

Comment: In that case, it's probably not safe until you can 1) guarantee it's not locked or 2) guarantee that this process is the only one still attached to that shared memory segment. If there are other processes attached, or if you have no way of telling if it's locked, then destroying it might cause bad things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head -

1. Use a semaphore (or a shared memory counter, for that matter)
2. Decide that the leader (the first process to create the mutex) is
   the one that will destroy it, and don't exit this process until the
   rest of them shut down.
3. Create the mutex externally, and delete it
   externally - processes take it for granted (maybe never even delete
   it; depends on the system)

etc...

Comment: Isn't 1 just kicking the can down the road? You'll have the same problem no?  2 and 3 aren't options for me.

Comment: Why would you have the same problem? Each user ups the ctr and releases it before exiting. Once it gets to 0, it kills the mutex and the semaphore. Out of curiosity, why aren't the two other valid for you?

Comment: Because you need to lock the counter no? The operation needs to be atomic. I can't do 2 because there's really no leader, the application design already dictates that each instance of the application determines its own lifetime. Similar reasons for 3.

Comment: If you use shared memory, you can do it with the mutex. If you use a semaphore, it's already thread safe